# Generating function and formula for the number of compositions of $n$ into $k$ parts, each of which is odd.

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Find the generating function for the number of compositions of $n$ into $k$ parts, each of which is odd. Apply algebraic manipulation and the formal power series expansion of some basic functions to find a formula for the coefficient of $x^n$ in the generating function.

I have that the generating function for the number of compositions comes from 
$$(x+x^3+x^5+...)^k=\bigg(\frac{x}{(1-x^2)}\bigg)^k=x^k\sum_{n=0}^\infty\begin{pmatrix}n+k-1\\k-1\end{pmatrix}x^{2n}$$
and I think that the formula I want to get too eventually is 
$$\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }n-k\text{ is odd}\\\\
\dbinom{\frac{n+k}2-1}{\frac{n-k}2},&\text{if }n-k\text{ is even}\;.
\end{cases}$$
I'm not sure how to get from the first formula to the second, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In the first formula, where did the sum over $n$ come from? You're summing an expression for $n$ to infinity that doesn't depend on $n$, so this series diverges.

Answer (score 1):

You are happy that the generating fuction is 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{N=0}^{\infty} \binom{N+k-1}{k-1} x^{2N+k} \text{    ?}
\end{eqnarray*}
This means there are $ \binom{N+k-1}{k-1}$ compositions (into $k$ odd parts) of $n$ where $n=2N+k$. So $n-k$ needs to be even (& the number of ways will be zero if it is odd) ... A little bit of algebra will lead to the conclusion you require.